# Bootstrap 3 theme for yii2 framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

Where can I find bootstrap 3 template for Yii2 framework besides ADMINLTE? It seems that Yii2 does not have multiple choice of Bootstrap template.

Comment: you need to look into the Bootstrap for the bootstrap themes not yii2 , it has the default theme integrated that it provides

Comment: You mean that all bootstrap themes can be integrated to yii2? I check on the documentation but most of them does not provide installation using composer. Sorry but I am still beginner to yii2.

Comment: any theme but there is not anything like installing the theme via composer instead you manually integrate them source files using the AssetManager and then register those assets in the layout file along with the required HTML for the layout.  for example look here about the [ADMINLTE](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/729/tutorial-about-how-to-integrate-yii2-with-fantastic-theme-adminlte) for sample how to integrate it manually, similarly you can do for any custom theme that is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

check this out: https://github.com/hiqdev/yii2-thememanager

you can also search on github lots of admin themes for your backend and themes for your frontend